# Jruby: Not able to start webrick server in jruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have install jruby 1.7.16 and rails 4.1.8 on my ubuntu machine. i have existing jruby application which i want to run using webbrick server but i am not able to run it. whenever i start webrick server using command rails s i am getting below error.

```
successful load of fcntl
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'.
Gem Load Error is: private method `require' called for Kernel:Module
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/administrator/Desktop/vitality_iq_project/analytics-core/config/application.rb:19:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:1:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1880:in `tap'
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `server'
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `(root)'
Bundler Error Backtrace:

       require at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
       require at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
       require at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75
       require at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler.rb:106
        (root) at /home/administrator/Desktop/vitality_iq_project/analytics-core/config/application.rb:19
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
        (root) at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:1
           tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1880
        server at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79
        server at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76
  run_command! at /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16@analytics-core/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
        (root) at script/rails:6
```

Below is my jruby version information

```
jruby -v
jruby 1.7.16 (1.9.3p392) 2014-09-25 575b395 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_101-b13 +jit [linux-amd64]
```

and my rails version is 4.1.8 . please help me to start server in Jruby application with rails.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an issue with Bundler 1.13.1 that is causing this - basically they transplant the `require` method while in JRuby 1.7 a visibility bug thus makes `Kernel::require` private.

3 thing you could do :

1. change Kernel.require visibility to be public (after Bundler is loaded)
2. downgrade to Bundler 1.12
3. upgrade to JRuby 1.7.26 (not yet released)

Comment: Kares.. you saved my life.....1000 thanks to you.... love you dear.... :)